# What is the reason of making try catch OutOfMemoryError and printStackTrace()?

Tags: java, android, try-catch, google-play-console

I undesrstand the try-catch statement, it means that it will try a piece of code and if it fails the catch section will be executed. What I don´t undesrtand is to use printStackTrace of an error in the catch section. I mean, why it would be useful to make the following code:

```
try{

}
catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If the code that is in the try section fails, an out of memory error will be printed according to the above code. What is the reason of making that? Won`t an error automatically be printed on the Google Play Console if the app crashes (the code of the try function)? I don´t understand the reason of printing an error if the Google Play Console is actually printing the stack trace of errors without need of using the try catch function...

Real example of code that I don't understand why the try catch is used:

```
public void playMediaPlayer(int id) {
            try {
                if (mediaPlayer != null || mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                }
    
                if (id == 1) {
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound1);
                } else if (id == 2) {
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound2);
    
                }
                if (PreferenceData.getSound(getApplicationContext())) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
        }
```

Comment: `OutOfMemoryError` extends from `Error`, a subclass of `Throwable` which should _not_ be caught in almost all circumstances. If I saw that try-catch, particularly in the context you posted, I'd be extremely wary of some other design or program flaw that caused it in the first place. Errors/exceptions are useful tools to detect problems in your code, not something to suppress (which at the very least, `#printStackTrace` still allows some visibility on the error occuring).

Comment: @Rogue according to your awnser, are you indirectly telling me that I souldn't use try catch in the example I posted as it is better to let the program crash and know the real exception as maybe if I use the try catch it will throw an OutOfMemoryError and there is a probability that it is not an OutOfMemoryError problem?

Comment: Moreso that if you have the error to begin with, there's likely an egregious problem elsewheres in the code, and this type of code would the medical equivalent of a bandaid for an amputation.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will automatically go to the Google Play Console because this will never crash.  The catch will prevent the exception from crashing you and continue on.  Which makes this dangerous code, unless you know what you're doing.  Generally something like this would only be seen in code working with caches, where a failed allocation would cause you to kick data out of a cache and retry.

As for why you may want to do this-  for debugging purposes.  You may want to see when it happens and information about the allocation (such as how big it was) while debugging.  It will only be for your personal use, as you'll never see the logcat of other devices.

Comment: So if I have undertood well, the app won't crash with a try catch because if the try section fails, it won't be executed so it won't be able to crash, right? Also, what is the difference between the StackTrace that Google Play Console would have printed if the try section didn't have "try-catch" (so that the app would have crashed )and the stacktrace of the catch statement (e.printStackTrace();) if it haD "try-catch" statement ?

Comment: No, if an error or exception is raised in `try`, then the `catch` block is executed next. Since the `catch` does not stop the program (but merely prints the error), it will (attempt to) be on its merry way. However, without anything addressing the concern for this error, you could wind right back up where you started (another OOMO).

Comment: @Lechius When an exception is thrown, it bubble up through the stack until something catches it.  If nothing catches it, the default exception handler for the thread handles it, and that's the handler that forces a crash and printing of the crash to a log.  By putting you're own catch there, you're stopping the propagation at that point and telling the exception system that you know how to handle it instead.  So after the catch, no exception will be sent to higher levels in the stack.  The exception ends when its caught.

Comment: @GabeSechan now the question would be, the default exception handler will give more information than using try catch with a specific exception (OutOfMemoryError in this case) becasue maybe it is not an OutOfMemoryError exception, right? So in conclusion, I should decide two paths, the first path is to use try catch and avoid the crash but with the limitation of not knowing what actually is making that code to crash  and the second path is not using try catch with the posibility that the app will crash but I will have better information about the crash to let me solve it later, am I right?

Comment: @Lechus OOM is a very specific error that makes it very difficult to recover from.  You should only ever catch it if you really know that you can fully recover-  you're creating a large but optional data structure and can continue functioning without it.  Basically unless you really know what you're doing and that it's actually ok, you shouldn't catch it.